# Debian package development process - sid to testing and back porting

Tags: development

I've been monitoring the process of [python-libusb1](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-libusb1) in Debian. Python-usb1 is required for the upgraded version of python-trezor to make it to testing. The author uploaded a new binary on May 12 and I see that the new version, [1.8](https://qa.debian.org/cgi-bin/vcswatch?package=python-libusb1), is pending upload and has been for 6 days. When does it go into the testing distribution?

The next step on the project for my team is to get it into buster-backports. Since I don't have a developer account I cannot upload it myself. I emailed the package maintainer as [listed here](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-trezor) but haven't heard back. Any suggestions on how to get python-trezor back ported once it uploads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps involved in getting `python-libusb1` into testing, starting from the state described in your question:

1. someone needs to upload the package — it’s ready in the VCS, but there’s still a manual step involved in getting it into the archive (but it turns out this has already been done);
2. the new version introduces a new package (`python3-usb1`), which means it will have to go through the NEW queue for validation, which might take a few days (this is the current state, see [the package’s entry in the queue](https://ftp-master.debian.org/new/python-libusb1_1.8-1.html));
3. if the package is approved, it will then enter unstable;
4. five days later, if no release-critical bugs are filed against it, it will become a candidate for mogration to testing;
5. at this point, as soon as all the conditions are met (in particular, its dependencies must all be in testing), it will enter testing.

To get `python-trezor` into backports, I’d recommend filing a wishlist bug against it, explaining why you want it there. That way you’ll reach more people than the listed maintainer, and someone else from the Python team might do it for you. You could also prepare the backport yourself and ask for sponsorship.

Comment: According to https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/python-libusb1 under 'Versions" it says NEW/unstable: 1.8-1. Does that mean it's in the NEW queue as per your step #2?

Comment: Ah yes, I hadn’t checked the NEW queue, so it is indeed already there.

Comment: I found the NEW queue here: https://ftp-master.debian.org/new.html some items have been in there for months, even a year. Will the same happen to python-libusb1?

Comment: I doubt it; when packages go through NEW because they’re adding a new binary package, they tend to be processed quickly (as opposed to completely new packages, which can take a while). The packages that spend a really long time in the queue are usually packages which are complex to review or have various issues that need to be sorted out (without justifying an outright rejection).

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: My last trip through NEW took a day (yesterday) ;-).